# The direction that gets me closest to a given point in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $p=\lambda_1 e_1+...+\lambda_n e_n$ where $e_i$ are standard basis vectors then if I want to find the component along which I can get closest to the point $p$ then it will just be $e_j$ with $j \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $\lambda_j$ satisfies $|\lambda_j| = max_{1 \leq i\ \leq n} \{|\lambda_1|,...,|\lambda_n|\}$ and the closest point to $p$ along this direction is $ \lambda_j e_j$. As $\lambda_j$ was maximum, we have
\begin{equation*}|\lambda_j| \geq \frac{|p|}{\sqrt{n}} \end{equation*} and
\begin{equation} |\lambda_j e_j - p | \leq \sqrt{\frac {n-1} {n} } |p|. \end{equation}

I am looking for similar estimates when $p$ is represented by a different basis. What can I say if the point $p= \alpha_1 x_1 +...+\alpha_n x_n$ where $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ are such that $ \angle(x_i, \text{span}(x_1,...,x_{i-1})) \geq \theta$ for $i=2,...,n$ and $\theta >0$. Can I choose a direction $x_j$, $j \in \{1,...,n\}$ and $\alpha>0$ so that $|\alpha x_j - p| \leq C |p|$ where $C<1$ and may depend on $n$ and $\theta$?

Also asked on mathoverflow - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385155/the-direction-that-gets-me-closest-to-a-given-point-in-mathbbrn?noredirect=1#comment982585_385155 .

Comment: Slight correction: select whichever $\lambda_j$ that satisfies $\color{blue}|\lambda_j\color{blue}|=\max_{1\le i\le n}\{\color{red}|\lambda_i\color{red}|\}$

Comment: Thank you, fixed.